# travelling to uk as a family from ireland

Tags: uk

I am travelling to UK with my family which includes my wife and 3 year old child from ireland.I made online application for my me and my wife in the gov.uk website and paid 111 euro each.Our childs name was included as asked in the application and do I have to make another application for my child?

Comment: Yes you do have to apply separately for the child, everyone needs to have their own application. But If you're Irish you don't even need a visa.

Comment: *Please add your nationality to the question.* (If Irish, you do not need any sort of visa to visit the UK.)